# How to capture data and answer with simulated data?

Tags: man-in-the-middle, wireshark, sniffing

I use Wireshark and other relatively smaller sniffers to make some tests.
I share my internet to my second PC. However, I have to spend much time for the following task, and want to know if i can do it easier:

1. From 2nd PC I have an application which sends data to `example.com` (I can capture that in Wireshark)
2. The site responds with "Hi Jenny" (I can to see that too)
3. Now I want to simulate and send different response: "Hello Monika" to 2nd pc.

How can I do that?

Comment: So, you want to be a man-in-the-middle and modify packets. I think you have a large amount of tutorials to help you through that ...

Comment: @schroeder i'll be glad you provided one of such tutorial, how can i search? "man-in-the-middle" or  ... ?

Comment: you could start there - mitmproxy is a all-in-one tool to do what you are asking

Comment: @schroeder thanks.. but i use Windows ( I tried to google and found some alternatives i think... THanks for help!